# Setting input type="file" using AngularJS expression not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a form builder application in Angular and have run into an odd bug in Chrome. I am dynamically setting a form input type based on a variable. This seems to work for all input types except for "file", which will always change to "text" in Chrome. A simple example is below:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="{{'file'}}" /><br />
  <input type="{{'color'}}" /><br />
  <input type="{{'button'}}" value="button" />
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x649Q/)

Comment: Yep,You should definetly file an issue on github,this is a serious bug.And since angular folks work at Google i'm pretty sure they can have that bug fixed.Maybe a ng-type directive could fix that(like ng-src or ng-href ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it sounds like a bug, but you can easily bypass it using [`ngAttr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings):

```
<input ng-attr-type="{{'file'}}" />
<input ng-attr-type="{{'color'}}" />
<input ng-attr-type="{{'button'}}" value="button" />
```

Comment: nice,i didnt know ng-attr !

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I also went ahead and filed an issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7632

Answer (score 0):

I propose a basic version of ng-type directive :

```
angular.module('ng').directive('ngType', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngType: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            $scope.$watch('ngType', function (newValue, old) {
                element.attr('type', newValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/camus/x649Q/2/

while the "bug" get fixed.

EDIT : blackhole answer is the right one.